# What is wrong in my Multi-Threading app using Qt (Error SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I'm newbie to Qt and i'm looking for multi-threading in Qt.
As i learned in [Qt Documents](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/threads-starting.html), i defined two class for two thread:

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QMutex>

class thread_a : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit thread_a(QObject *parent = 0);
    int counter;

protected:
    void run();
};
```

and in CPP file:

```
#include "thread_a.h"

thread_a::thread_a(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    counter=0;
}

void thread_a::run()
{
    counter++;
}
```

Second thread class is same, but with `counter--` in `run()` method.
Then i run this two threads from `main.ccp`. No problem.  But when i run this two thread on an slot, a problem goes occurred.  A dialog with "Signal Recived" as title and is say me "The inferior stopped because it recieved a signal from operating system. Signal Name: SIGSEGV , Signal Meaning: Segmentation fault "

What is wrong?

**Update:**
This is my slot:

```
public slots:
    void run_threads(bool);
```

and

```
void MainWindow::run_threads(bool bl)
{
    thread_a a;
    thread_b b;
    a.start();
    b.start();
}
```

and i connected a PushButton to this slot by:

```
QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)),
                          this, SLOT(run_threads(bool)));
```

Comment: Please post the code you use to "run the two threads on a slot".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your slot creates two instances of your thread classes, starts them, and the exits.  At that point the function returns and the instances fall out of scope, and thus destructed.  You should retain access to the instances so that they are not destructed and possibly reuse them.

```
class MainWindow {
//...other stuff
  public slots:
    void run_threads(bool);
  private:
    thread_a a;
    thread_b b;
//...other stuff
};
```

and

```
void MainWindow::run_threads(bool bl)
{
   if(!a.isRunning())
     a.start();

   if(!b.isRunning())
     b.start();
}
```